# Swift / HTTPS - Invalid header HTTP header field was received

Tags: ios, swift, apache, https, urlsession

I just received a weird error message from my URLSession class when communicating with HTTPS server:

```
HTTP/2 error encountered on Connection 1 (Code -531): Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [upgrade], value: [h2,h2c]
Task <E41376D8-2894-416B-A887-CCB1C53E6F1B>.<1> HTTP load failed, 519/0 bytes (error code: 100 [1:100])
Task <E41376D8-2894-416B-A887-CCB1C53E6F1B>.<1> finished with error [100] Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x600002ccb570 [0x7fff8062d750]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bb0fa5deaf0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

This occurs periodically with no response. But, when I tried the same function more, it responded successfully. Of course, there was no error like this when I communicate with HTTP server.
It seems the request is successfully received from server.
Just cannot received on the client.

Here's the code where I try to communicate with server :

```
func sendRequest(to reqUrl: String, completion: HttpClient.CallBack? = nil) {
    var urlString = reqUrl

    urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)!
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("QHttpClient: Unreachable URL")
        completion?(.unreachableUrl, AppString.Error.Unknown, nil)
        return
    }
    
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: self.timeoutInterval)

    for (key, value) in self.headerValues ?? [:] {
        if request.value(forHTTPHeaderField: key) != nil { continue }
        request.addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
    }

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=" + kBoundaryString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            
    var body = ""
            
    let jsonWriter = SBJsonWriter()
    for (key, value) in self.parameters?.dict ?? [:] {
        body += "--\(kBoundaryString)\r\n"
        body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(key)\""
                
        if let valueArray = value as? [Any], let valueString = jsonWriter.string(with: valueArray) {
            body += "\r\n\r\n\(valueString)\r\n"
        } else if let valueString = value as? String {
            body += "\r\n\r\n\(valueString)\r\n"
        } else {
            body += "\r\n\r\n\(value)\r\n"
        }
    }
            
    for attachment in attachments ?? [] {
        body += "--\(kBoundaryString)\r\n"
        body += "Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"\(attachment.key)\""
                
        if attachment.type == .Image {
            let fileContent = String(data: attachment.data, encoding: .utf8)!
            body += "; filename=\"\(attachment.fileName)\"\r\n"
                      + "Content-Type: \"content-type header\"\r\n\r\n\(fileContent)\r\n"
        }
    }
            
    body += "--\(kBoundaryString)--\r\n";
    httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)!

    request.httpBody = httpBody
    request.setValue("\([UInt8](httpBody).count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    self.task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let self = self, response as? HTTPURLResponse == nil {
            // ********* Error **********
            return
        }
        // Do something
    })
    task!.resume()
}
```

Is there any way to avoid the error and get response normally?

FYI, the server using HTTP 1.1 protocols and based on Apache.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you share how your `self.headerValues` is created? What values you put here? And what is your `kBoundaryString `?

Comment: @Zico Hi. This code is part of a custom class which is communicating with server. So, I put some header values as a dictionary like Authorization token. kBoundaryString is a constant string:    private let kBoundaryString = "---modoorepboundary236739405175924702888539212340aca3742955c---".

Comment: And, I'm 100% sure that this error occurs without any relationship with those values

Comment: Any luck on the solution ?

Comment: This solution worked for me - https://help.poralix.com/articles/iphone-does-not-open-https-site-safari-nsposixerrordomain